# String pattern replace a column

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2005, t-sql, string-matching

Since it's not that easy to perform regex in SQL I'll need some advice in how to solve this problem.

I have a column with the following type of data:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit **$%foo##amet%$**, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
>   Nullam odio risus, mollis a interdum vitae, rutrum id leo. Pellentesque 
>   dapibus lobortis mattis. Praesent at nisi a orci commodo scelerisque
>   **$%bar##%$** eget id dui. Morbi est arcu, ultricies et consequat ac, 
>   pretium sed mi. Quisque iaculis pretium congue. Etiam ullamcorper sapien 
>   eu mauris tristique at venenatis mauris ultricies. Proin eu vehicula enim. 
>   Vestibulum aliquam, mauris ac tempus vulputate, odio mauris rhoncus purus, 
>   id suscipit velit erat quis magna.

The bold text I need to match, and it needs to be replaced with the text found in the second part.

Meaning:

- `$%foo##amet%$` becomes `amet`
- `$%bar##%$` becomes an empty string.

The pattern as a regex would be something like `\$%[^#]+?##([^%]*?)%\$`

I can't really use that though since regex is not really supported in tsql...

Any advice?

Comment: I suggest you doing that in a programming language and not in SQL. SQL is not optimized for such things. It's a DB query language and not a text processing optimized language.

Comment: @m0skit0 Problem with that would be performance, its a table thats deleted and filled each night with over 900.000 rows

Comment: In fact the performance hit would be more using SQL IMHO. A test would clear this.

Comment: @red-X: if you're worried about performance - then I'd seriously give SQL-CLR a try! Since the .NET code would be executed within SQL Server, you don't have any of the network traffic and thus better performance overall ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it with this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ReplaceWithDefault]
(
   @InputString VARCHAR(4000)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Pattern VARCHAR(100) SET @Pattern = '$[%]_%##%[%]$'
    -- working copy of the string
    DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(4000) SET @Result = @InputString
    -- current match of the pattern
    DECLARE @CurMatch VARCHAR(500) SET @curMatch = ''
    -- string to replace the current match
    DECLARE @Replace VARCHAR(500) SET @Replace = ''
    -- start + end of the current match
    DECLARE @Start INT
    DECLARE @End INT
    -- length of current match
    DECLARE @CurLen INT
    -- Length of the total string -- 8001 if @InputString is NULL
    DECLARE @Len INT SET @Len = COALESCE(LEN(@InputString), 8001)

    WHILE (PATINDEX('%' + @Pattern + '%', @Result) != 0) 
    BEGIN
        SET @Replace = ''

        SET @Start = PATINDEX('%' + @Pattern + '%', @Result)
        SET @CurMatch = SUBSTRING(@Result, @Start, @Len)

        SET @End = PATINDEX('%[%]$%', @CurMatch) + 2
        SET @CurMatch = SUBSTRING(@CurMatch, 0, @End)

        SET @CurLen = LEN(@CurMatch)

        SET @Replace = REPLACE(RIGHT(@CurMatch, @CurLen - (PATINDEX('%##%', @CurMatch)+1)), '%$', '')

        SET @Result = REPLACE(@Result, @CurMatch, @Replace)
    END
    RETURN(@Result)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

The best option you have is using a nested `REPLACE` with fixed matching string:

```
SELECT REPLACE(
           REPLACE(YourColumn, '$[%]foo##amet[%]$', 'amet'), '$[%]bar##[%]$', '')
```

Of course, that doesn't have the flexibility of regexes....

Or you could design a SQL-CLR regex library (or [find one of the pre-existing ones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx)) and include those into your SQL Server - from 2005 on, SQL Server *can* execute .NET code, and something like a regex library is a perfect example for extending T-SQL with .NET capabilities.

Comment: Since a lot of other software depend on the DB and i have no experience with CLR's I'm a little hesitant in adding them. There are a lot(understatement) of different combinations so the first suggestions not gonna do it either.

Comment: @red-X: well, in that case, you probably can't do it **within** SQL Server, but you'd have to read the data from a .NET app and do the pattern matching/replacement there, and then update any rows changed.....

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the following code:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(YourColumn, ' $%amet%$ ', ' amet '), ' $%bar%$ ', ' ')
```

The % character represents "Any string of zero or more characters" as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx).
You need to put spaces to identify only single words :)

Comment: The strings can be pretty much anything so that would be a LOT of replaces that need to be edited into the query anytime another one gets added so thats out of the question.

Comment: ohh, it's not only those two examples. Are they allways one word? (without spaces) and do you want to replace the words that have amet or bar?

Comment: I want to replace the complete pattern from $ to $ with the second word (so amet and the empty string in the example)

Comment: If you just want to replace ..amet.. and ...bar.. for bar and empty you can use my answer.